# After clone dropdown keep value of one selected option and reset the second dropdown jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with 2 linked dropdowns that I must clone on select the **Services** dropdown. The second dropdown is popped up according to the selection of the first dropdown *(this part works)*.
I successfully clone them. However, each clone must keep the selected value of the **Area** dropdown and the **Services** dropdown must keep the result but with unselected option.

```
        <table class="table table-sm table-striped mb-0">
    <thead>
    <tr class="bg-th">
    <th >
    Country
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
    Towns
    </th>

    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td >
    <select class="form-select" onChange="center_area_on_change(this);">
    <option value=""></option>

    </select>
    </td>
    <td style="width:280px;display:block">

    <select style='width:100%' onChange="getTarifDataSeguroPrivado(this);">


    </select>


    </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
    </table>
```

*The **center_area_on_change function** pops up the *Services* dropdown on select.

*The **getTarifDataSeguroPrivado function**  calls the function that clones the row (*function addRow*).

```
function getTarifDataSeguroPrivado(dropDown) {

  addRow();

}
```

[image]
The addRow() function.*

```
function addRow() {

var tableBody = $('#table-tarifario').find("tbody");
var trLast = tableBody.find("tr:last");

var trNew = trLast.clone();


trNew.find('select').val(function(index, value) {
return trLast.find('select').eq(index).val();
});

trLast.after(trNew);

}
```

1. How can I keep the selected value of the area dropdown, and keep the result of the services dropdown with not selected data when a new row is cloned?

2- I tried to use select2, but it cannot apply to all the dropdowns, although I destroy them like:
*$("select").select2("destroy");*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I fully understand what you are asking. Also, I found it difficult to reproduce your issue because you provided code seems incomplete - the `<select>` menus have no options and the table selector, `'#table-tarifario'`, does not exist.

However, I am providing some code that should at least get you close to what you are looking for. I am taking the index of the selected option in the last row and using it to set the selected option on the new row.

```js
function center_area_on_change (el) {
  console.log(el);
}

function getTarifDataSeguroPrivado(dropDown) {
  addRow();
}

function addRow() {
  $('table select').select2('destroy');
  var tableBody = $('table').find("tbody");
  var trLast = tableBody.find("tr:last");
  var trNew = trLast.clone();

  const lastSelectedCountryIndex = trLast.find('select').eq(0).find('option:selected').index();
 
trNew.find('select').eq(0).find('option').eq(lastSelectedCountryIndex).prop('selected', true);

  trLast.after(trNew);
  $('table select').select2();
}

$('table select').select2();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <table class="table table-sm table-striped mb-0">
   <thead>
     <tr class="bg-th">
       <th>
         Country
       </th>
       <th scope="col">
         Towns
       </th>

     </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <select class="form-select" onChange="center_area_on_change(this);">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option>Country 1</option>
            <option>Country 2</option>
            <option>Country 3</option>
            <option>Country 4</option>
         </select>
       </td>
       <td style="width:280px;display:block">

         <select style='width:100%' onChange="getTarifDataSeguroPrivado(this);">
          <option></option>
          <option>Town 1</option>
          <option>Town 2</option>
          <option>Town 3</option>
          <option>Town 4</option>
          <option>Town 5</option>
         </select>


       </td>

     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Alternatively, if you have `value` attributes on your options, you could do this by value:

```
function addRow() {
  var tableBody = $('table').find("tbody");
  var trLast = tableBody.find("tr:last");
  var trNew = trLast.clone();

  const lastSelectedCountryInddex = trLast.find('select').eq(0).find('option:selected').index();
 
  const lastSelectedCountry = trLast.find('select').eq(0).val();
  
  trNew.find('select').eq(0).val(lastSelectedCountry);

  trLast.after(trNew);
}
```

Update: When using [Select2](https://select2.org/), you must be sure to remove Select2 - `$('select').select2('destroy')` - before cloning. Once the cloned row has been inserted into the DOM, you can re-apply Select2 - `$('select').select2()`. I have updated the code example to use Select2.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The table selector '#table-tarifario' was omitted when I rewrote the codes. You really teach me how to use the index-related selectors eq. Please have a look at the second question. How to use select2 on the dropdowns. Although I destroy it before cloning it still cannot work. After that, I will accept your answer. Or I can accept it before that. Many thanks.

Comment: @Diasline: I have updated my answer to use Select2.

Comment: Thank you. I see that your code work. But, when I apply it to my page, after the new row has been inserted, the select2 effect is removed and I have this error in:  select2.min.js:2 The select2('destroy') method was called on an element that is not using Select2.

Comment: @Diasline: Presumably you have other `<select>` elements on the page that are not using Select2. Can you scope your selector when invoking `'disable'` so as to include only `<select>` elements using `select2`?

Comment: On the page, I have only 2 select, as I posted. Do you mean I must disable the select2 after destroy it?

Comment: @Diasline: I don't think I am going to be able to help without seeing an example of the situation you are describing. If you can reproduce the issue in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), then I can try to help. Otherwise, I can just advise you to make sure you have applied `.select2()` _before_ you call `.select2('destroy')`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253258/discussion-between-diasline-and-76484).